# What are the possible causes for 'invalid grant' error while using Google Analytics API and how can it be fixed?

Tags: google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to implement a server to server call for google analytics. Trying to obtain an access token for the same using below API:-
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

Added the below URL parameter for the same:-
grant_type :urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion :

Getting the below error:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."
}
iat and exp values are 2500.

tried above call and got
Getting the below error:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."
}

Can someone help here.

Comment: please include [example]  authorization header needs to be an access token what ever you are passing isn't an access token

Comment: I am trying to get an access token from this call. There are no headers passed int his call, but just the below URL parameters:              grant_type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer        assertion :  Unable to pass the excat assertion here as it is too long.

Comment: Do you have some link in the documentation where that grant type exists.  Its not one i am familiar with.   What language are you using?